# Email Send record for tracking Triggered Sends from Salesforce

Tags: marketing-cloud

We are using Marketing Cloud to send emails to customers from Salesforce. Our solution is as follows:

1. User clicks a button in Salesforce, on Opportunity screen to initiate the email send
2. Custom code is used to generate emails to be sent by Exact Target.
3. We are using STEPS 5-7 defined in the link (https://help.exacttarget.com/en/technical_library/web_service_guide/technical_articles/retrieving_tracking_results_for_one_to_one_triggered_sends/) for the Triggered Send
4. We are successfully sending out emails to the customers and a BCC email is received by the person who initiated the email (Step 1).
5. We are also creating a record in Email Send (SendDefinition__c) object in Salesforce, when we send the emails. This is a custom object created through the Salesforce ET integration v5 package. The Email Send object is modified to hold our custom unique key. While creating the record in Email Send object, we populate this custom unique key. Other fields are not populated.
6. After 12 hours, the Email Send record is updated with the Send Status = Failed and Message with the error "Errors could not be resolved within 12 hours".
7. An email is sent out to the person who initiated the process (Step 1) containing the error in Email Send record.

Please help us figure out where the error is coming from. As the customers are receiving the emails and the tracking as per (https://help.exacttarget.com/en/technical_library/web_service_guide/technical_articles/retrieving_tracking_results_for_one_to_one_triggered_sends/) is also working fine.

Thanks,
lmho

Comment: This is an odd one... Have you checked the API user etc? I would log a case with Marketing Cloud Support. Let us know how you go.

Comment: So step 1-4 are completing without any issues and the email is going out, correct?  On step 5, is this attempting to create a new "Send" or is it trying to create a Tracking Record/Job within your Salesforce Instance?  Are you using the new Triggered Send feature in your Salesforce Instance or is this done via API/APEX code in your environment?  Has this ever worked for you in the past or is this something new you're trying to implement?  I know the email send object (Custom Object Definition) is managed, meaning that you may only edit certain attributes.

Comment: The Steps 1-4 are done using Marketing Cloud UI. We are creating a new Triggered Send record in Marketing Cloud from Salesforce (Step 5). The tracking info within Salesforce is gathered using (Steps 6 and Step 7). Steps 5-7 are all done using Apex code which utilizes Marketing Cloud API. The feature is working fine, we are able to send out the emails and receive tracking info back. But we are also receiving the error “Errors could not be resolved within 12 hours”. Any ideas why are we receiving this error.

Comment: I've only ever seen this error when the actual send fails and cannot go out.  This error is specifically mentioned on this link.  Not sure if this is an Enterprise 2.0 account and if there are issues with the permissions or BU setup on the integration.  Hopefully the link will provide some insight:  https://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/documentation/integrated_products__crm_and_web_analytic_solutions/exacttarget_salesforce_integration_v5/salesforce_v5_troubleshooting_guide/